# volume of an n-dimensional pyramid generated by delaunay triangulations

Tags: geometry, volume, computational-geometry, triangulation

I have read the Delaunay triangulation for $n$ dimensions. assume that I have $d$ points. using a Delaunay triangulation algorithm, it makes $P$ pyramids. I want to know which of these pyramids has a smaller volume.

I already read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302005/finding-volume-of-an-n-dimensional-pyramid-numerically) question, but it can't help me, because of each pyramid has 4 vertexes and each vertex has $n$ dimensions. how can I calculate the volume of pyramids?

Comment: The question at the link has the exact answer to yours: in nd you don't have pyramids, but simplexes, and you can find their volume in the answer.

Comment: Vertex is a point and its dimension is 0.

Comment: @N74 the question at the links said:`If you have n+1 points in n dimensions ` but I don't have n+1 points. I have 4 vertexes which have d dimensions.

Comment: With $4$ points in $n$ dimensions you don't contain a volume, so you don't have a triangulation... It is like as you asked for a 2d problem "what is the area contained by these 2 points". You need at least another point to draw a closed figure, $n+1$ when $n=2$.